# Communication between EKS node and EKS Fargate pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster, where a code is ran as service 24/7 on the node. Now if i create a fargate profile on the same cluster, can the pods deployed by the Fargate profile communicate with the EKS service node which is running on the same cluster? As the pods does makes calls to that service for data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you have same cluster and all node/pod/service under same VPC, any pod deployed on Fargate will be able to communicate with any other pod/node that is deployed on node group.

You can use FQDN of service name to communicate with other pod deployed on another namespace.

FQDN (fully qualified domain name) of any service is

<service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local

You can read more about DNS of pod and service from here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/